# jquery event on Modal dialog close button

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog region in my oracle apex page. The region has inline dialog template. I want to trigger an action when the user clicks the close button of the dialog . So I write the code

```
$(".ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function (e) {
      alert('Hi');
      // actions
});
```

The HTML code of the dialog close button is

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" 
role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Close">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button>
```

But it doesn't work. What might be wrong with me?

Comment: Add some HTML snippet.

Comment: Added the HTML codes now.

Comment: [Beginner Concepts: How CSS Selectors Work](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$(".ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-icon-only.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function (e) {
  alert('Hi');
  // actions
});
```

Your `<button>` element have multiple selectors, so you need to use a period for all selectors and with no space (because these all are declare same element).

Also, if you use only one selector, it will be more clear. You don't need to use all selectors.

Like:

```
$(".ui-button").click(function (e) { alert('Hi'); // actions });
```

Comment: No explanation at all? Explanations are the reason why SO is so famous. Even if your answer is right, it is a "low quality" one.

Comment: just put the period before each class name and remove the spaces. Thank you :)

Comment: Explanation : Just because your `<button>` element have multiple selectors so you need to use period for all selectors and with no space (because these all are declare same element).

Also if you use only one selector it will be more clear, you don't need to use all selectors. like

`$(".ui-button").click(function (e) {
  alert('Hi');
  // actions
});`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for your kind advice :) I will remember it all the time.

Comment: I used your explanations in comments to improve your answer. Notice that you always can edit your answer. There is a link below it to do that. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you very much. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Its look like you have entered the wrong class in the selector**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-icon-only.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function (e) {
  alert('Hi');
  // actions
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" 
role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Close">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button>
```